# An extremal combinatorial problem over Finite rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, ring-theory, extremal-combinatorics, finite-rings

Let $q$ be an odd number and $g_i = (g_{i1} g_{i2} \dots g_{ir}) \in \Bbb Z_q^r$ a list of vectors with $i\in\{1,\ldots,L\}$. Let each $g_i$ have $0 < k < r$ zero entries.

What is the maximum size of a subset $T\subseteq\Bbb Z_{q}^{r}$ such that for every pair of vectors $a,b \in T$, $a-b \neq \pm g_i$ for all $i\in\{1,\ldots,L\}$?

Comment: $T$ doesn't appear to be well defined. In the case that $a-b=g[i]$ and $c-a=g[j]$, how do we know which of $(a,b),(c,a)$ is a member and who isn't? Also, without any knowledge of $g$, I'm not sure what could be said of $T$.

Comment: $a-b=g[i]$ and $c-a=g[j]$ is fine. Both pairs in the list since $i \neq j$

Comment: The point is if you have $a-b=b-c=d-a=g[i]$, you can only pick one of the pairs.

Comment: Yes, but which?

Comment: pick any! Since $g[i] \neq g[j]$, this will be fine. If you have $a-b=b-c=d-a=g[i]$ and $a-b1=b1-c1=d1-a=g[j]$, then any one of $(a,b),(b,c),(d,a)$ and one of $(a,b1),(b1,c1),(d1,a)$ is fine.